# IF statement in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I need help. I have this query:

```
SELECT IF(book_id=2, 'NTR', if(book_id=5,'CBC', if(book_id=1,'CBC','Repair')) AS   
'STATUS',
COUNT(IF(book_id=2, 'NTR', if(book_id=5,'CBC', if(book_id=1,'CBC','Repair'))) AS 
'TOTAL'
FROM book_entry AS b
WHERE last_updated=(SELECT last_updated FROM book_entry WHERE book_code=b.book_code ORDER  
BY last_updated DESC) AND (SELECT description FROM book_categori AS c, book_item AS i  
WHERE c.id=i.id AND i_item_code=b.item_code) = "NOVEL" 
GROUP BY IF(book_id=2, 'NTR', if(book_id=5,'CBC', if(book_id=1,'CBC','Repair')))
```

Total data for this table is 128. Actually, there are more than 3 status but I just want to get 3 status (NTR, CBC and the other status I group it in 1 status that I set it as 'Repair'). From the query I create above, I got this result:

```
STATUS      TOTAL
---------------
CBC         70
Repair      58
```

This is not like the result I want. What I want is like this:

```
STATUS      TOTAL
-----------------
CBC         70
Repair      58
NTR         0
```

Actually there are no id for 'NTR' which is means id=2 is actually null but I want to include it in the result like above.

Can anyone teach me what I need to change in my query to get that result?

Comment: If you based your query on book_entry you can't show "NTR 0" because doesn't exist any entry with that id. Please create a typing table about your categories where you store the category name: CBC, Repair, NTR and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you want a table for status - with fields for say status_id int, status varchar

Add records for the CBC, NTR and Repair

Then add a column for status_id into book_entry and update as appropriate

Then your query can join onto the status table - something like:

```
select status.status, count(*) total
from status left join book_entry 
on status.status_id = book_entry.status_id
join book_categori 
on book_entry.item_code = book_categori.i_item_code
where book_categori.description = 'NOVEL'
group by status.status
```

( can't figure out what you are trying to do with the first part of your where clause

```
last_updated=(SELECT last_updated FROM book_entry WHERE book_code=b.book_code 
ORDER BY last_updated DESC)
```

I don't think it will have any effect except making the query harder to read.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I already found other solution for this problem. I change the query where I'm not using IF statement to get the result but I use UNION to combine all data I want and luckily it's working. Hehe..